# Copying 15 million records to a new table/server

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Good day. I need to move 15 Million Records from one MySQL table to a new table on other schemas. This is a live system and time is a problem. The table I need to move is a history table and isn't important for day to day business. I can't leave the table as it is part of a bigger upgrade I am doing.

I tried just moving the data with basic sql in a test environment but this doesn't work; the server kicks me out after 20min.

What would be the best way of moving the data?

I am a C# programmer  if someone has a coding solution

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

Comment: Just [dumping the whole table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9309) doesn't work either?

Comment: Is it the "same server" / different scheme - or an all-new production database (on a different host?)

Comment: I'd make a transaction that moves the data over in chunks of like 10,000 rows (or an appropriate number depending on how much data is in each row).  I personally wouldn't do it all at once but I guess it depends on how much of a beast your server is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is important to know how you connect the two. Is they reside inside single MSSQL instance or different? Because it seems like you try to download entire history into memory of your application...

Either way, you can always move your data in batches. For example, you can do it in Entity Framework like this:

```
using(var src = new MyFirstContext())
using(var tr = src.DataBase.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommited)) //this will speed up read of history
{
    int i = 0;
    const int batchSize = 100000;
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var batch = src.History.AsNoTracking().Skip(i*batchSize).Take(batchSize).ToList();
            if(!batch.Any())
            {
                break;
            }
            using(var dst = new MySecondContext())
            {
                dst.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                foreach(var ent1 in batch)
                {
                    var ent2 = Map(ent1); //here you can perform map of one history type of row to another.
                    dst.Set<HistoryRowFromSecondDatabase>().Add(ent2);
                }
                dst.SaveChanges();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //this is really helpful scope in case of exception.
        //save variable 'i', so you can start from the point you left last time.
        //Because by default your data is commited under ReadCommited transaction, it is pretty safe to rely only on
        //single 'i' variable. Even if you add some new data in source table.
    }
}
```

I have not tested this, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

take a look to Bulk Import/Export... i think it's the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

There are few options with which you can achieve it.

- Creating linked server to move using T-SQL scripts.
- Create a service file that will do the task for you.
- SSIS is an option that you can explore.
- Export/Import.